# Unable to scroll on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, scroll

My site won't scroll vertically at all on mobile. I know it's happening on Android and Blackberry OS. I've literally removed each css as well as each html and js element and tested and it still won't scroll. Hopefully someone here can figure out where the problem is. I honestly don't know what else to do here. It's been trying to find help for a couple weeks now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't scroll for ipad either. Get rid of the image slider.

Comment: I tried that but only in dev mode. I feel dumb. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you emulate the android device in chrome it works fine, however the device (my case nexus 5) does freeze. You have a few seconds of scrolling before it freezes which to me would point to the ajax call in application.js.

I would start by handling the exception thrown when

```
download_link = $('#download').attr('href');
```

returns undefined and throws an error on the line below.

```
$('#download').attr('href', download_link.replace(regex_version, version));
```